# "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity" while creating Generic DAO interface in Room

Tags: java, android, persistence, dao, android-room

I am using Room architecture component for persistence. I have created generic DAO interface to avoid boilerplate code. 
[Room Pro Tips](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)

But my code doesn't compile saying "Error:(21, 19) error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it." for the Generic class T.

```
interface BaseDao<T> {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(T... entity);

@Update
void update(T entity);

@Delete
void delete(T entity);
}

@Dao
public abstract class ReasonDao implements BaseDao<ReasonDao> {

   @Query("SELECT * from Reason")
   abstract public List<Reason> getReasons();

}
```

Is there anything I am missing here. 
It works like this [here](https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/1c78858f286d196d545c038a71a3e864)

Comment: where is your data class?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had initially followed the method used in Kotlin, but that gives the error in Java code. 
Two quick changes fixed it for me

- Change BaseDao to Abstract class
- Added @Dao annotation to the BaseDao

Please find the code below and now it runs properly

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseDao<T> {

   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   abstract void insert(T entity);

   @Update
   abstract void update(T entity);

   @Delete
   abstract void delete(T entity);
 }

 @Dao
 public abstract class ReasonDao extends BaseDao<Reason>{

    @Query("SELECT * from Reason")
    abstract public List<Reason> getReasons();

  }
```

Comment: Hello, according to my experience. When you get such error, try to comment all methods and sequentially uncomment each of them and rebuild every time.

Answer (score 69):

Changed in gradle from this:

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
```

to this:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: This one solved mine!

Comment: that is the solution for me, but why? I added kapt in plugins !

Comment: Changing this setting just led me to other errors. I just had to change the room version in the  build.gradle (project) file as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73304737/1722652

Comment: instead of doing this add the "ktx" compiler `implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$android_room"` instead and leave kapt alone

Comment: This solve my problem and save my day. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you faced this issue in Kotlin 1.7.10+ and Room < 2.4.2, upgrading Room to 2.4.3 fixes the issue.

From Room's changelog for 2.4.3:
Fixed an issue that would cause Room to not recognize suspend functions in Kotlin 1.7

This issue was due to using `suspend` functions for insert/delete in interfaces:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236612358

Comment: Solved the error for me

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that in my build.gradle, the version of Kotlin I was using was 1.5.0

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.0"
```

But as far as I understood, this version of Kotlin along with Room and coroutines doesn’t work well.
Was able to resolve the issue by downgrading the Kotlin version to:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32"
```

Solved! Thank me later

Comment: That works for me also.

Answer (score 6):

remove suspend,then it will work.

```
@Dao
interface FoodDao {

     @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     fun upsert(meal: Meal): Long


    @Query("SELECT * FROM food_tables")
    fun getAllFood(): LiveData<List<Meal>>


    @Delete
    fun deleteFood(meal: Meal)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you specified ***ReasonDao*** type as generic parameter instead of ***Reason***.

Original code:

```
@Dao
public abstract class ReasonDao implements BaseDao<ReasonDao> {

   ...

}
```

Correct code:

```
@Dao
public abstract class ReasonDao implements BaseDao<Reason> {

   ...

}
```

where ***Reason*** is the type marked with ***@Entity*** annotation.

By the way, this is fixed in the accepted answer, but is not mentioned in the changelist :)

Answer (score 4):

Changed in gradle this: kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion" to this: annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

Doing this solution served me partially but when trying to insert a date in the database it did not work for me so try kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion" and rather change room_version to the latest stable version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#groovy
ependencies {

```
//**
def room_version = '2.4.0'
def activityVersion = '1.4.0'
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
// Room and Lifecycle dependencies
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
//kotlin extensions for coroutine support with room
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

//kotlin extension for coroutine support with activities
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion"
//**
```

This is how it worked for me correctly

Answer (score 2):

This is a version error. Try updating your room dependencies.

I changed mine from:`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"`

To :`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried to save to DB non-Entity objects. Then replaced with Entity class (contains `@Entity(tableName = "your_table", indices = [Index("your_key")])`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe is that you have missed to give `Entity` annotation to T class. For example `Reason` class should have `@Entity` and give it to ReasonDao class. Like:

`@Dao
 public abstract class ReasonDao extends BaseDao<Reason>{}`

Answer (score 1):

Do not replace `kapt` with `annotationProcessor`

Try this instead

```
def room_version = "2.5.1"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// To use Coroutine features with room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is missing here is the Data class. Generally,
> @Entity represents objects you want to store,
>
> - Room entity includes fields for each column inside the
> - table in the database

```
@Entity(tableName="something") data class YourData()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has a "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it " error when using Kotlin in the dao , you should try using  @JvmSuppressWildcards annotation on your functions. eg.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM materials")
 @JvmSuppressWildcards
 fun getAllMaterials(): LiveData<List<MaterialModel>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to store a data class object into the Room Database. The error says that the parameter for `Insert` should be a class which has an annotation of `@Entity` so I created a table (entity) which has same values as data class and stored them successfully

Answer (score 0):

One small mistake I did was
I did not annotate my data class with the @Entity annotation

Table declaration

```
@Entity // Check if you have used this annotation or not
data class fooTable(){
...
}
```

In DAO

```
@Dao
interface myDao{
  @Insert
  suspend fun addFoo(fooObj: fooTable)
  }
}
```

If you are trying to insert a row in a table in Room DB then the corresponding data class should be annotated with @Entity annotation

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing the version room matters too, like I changed my room version from 2.2.6 to 2.4.3 and it worked. if the Kotlin version is low it's better to use a lower version of the room as well if the Kotlin version is high it's better to use a higher version too.

Answer (score 0):

In My case dependence version issue. I have upgreade dependence now working fine.
so make sure dependence is according to kotlin version.

```
**def room_version = "2.5.1"**
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I accidentally used **vararg** inside the method:

```kotlin
@Insert
fun insertAll(vararg postDbModels: Array<PostDbModel>)
```

To fix this issue I just removed vararg and using an Array of @Entity class model instead:

```kotlin
@Insert
fun insertAll(postDbModels: Array<PostDbModel>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")

implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion")

// Dependencies for working with Architecture components
// You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

// Room components
implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

androidTestImplementation ("androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion")

// Lifecycle components
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion")

// Kotlin components
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion")
api ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines")
api ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines")`
```

Comment: Please add a description text.