# Room : Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: java, android, dao, android-room

At first, i know this is [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015280/type-of-the-parameter-must-be-a-class-annotated-with-entity-while-creating-ge) but marked answer didn't solve the error.

I'm trying to create generic Dao interface within my Room Persistance Library following [this guide](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) but cannot solve error "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it" for the generic **T** in GenericDao.

GenericDao:

```
@Dao
public interface GenericDao<T> {
    @Insert
    long insert(T object);

    @Update
    void update(T... objects);

    @Delete
    void delete(T... objects);
}
```

Inherited Dao:

```
@Dao
public abstract class ExerciseDao implements GenericDao<Exercise> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercises")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Exercise>> getAllExercises();

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exercises",
    indices = {@Index(value = {"name"}, unique = true)})
public class Exercise {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
     int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "muscle_part")
    private int musclePart;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_shown")
    private boolean isShown;

    public Exercise(String name, int musclePart, boolean isShown) {
        this.name = name;
        this.musclePart = musclePart;
        this.isShown = isShown;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMusclePart() {
        return musclePart;
    }

    public void setMusclePart(int musclePart) {
        this.musclePart = musclePart;
    }

    public boolean isShown() {
        return isShown;
    }

    public void setShown(boolean shown) {
        isShown = shown;
    }
}
```

I've tried:

- Change GenericDao to abstract class.
- Add/remove @Dao annotation in GenericDao
- Add Generic Entity
- Override methods in child Daos
- ...

But always with the error.
Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: add your entity class

Comment: @Redman updated