# kapt vs annotationProcessor related error. (error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/prefilling-room-database-with-json-data-in-android/). When I use `kapt` I get error: `error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion); ^` and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589298) I changed to `annotationProcessor` but I got error `NoteDatabase_Impl does not exist`. So on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323956) they suggest to use `kapt` instead to remove that error. Later answer is older.

So what I should do to solve this at app launch?

build.gradle script:

```
// Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

// Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"

//Room Database
def room_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// Kotlin Extensions and Coroutine support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
```

Comment: You should provide more details about what your entity and DAO files look like. It sounds like you might be missing something important there.

Comment: @BrianYencho all in the tutorial link.

Comment: I recreated the project and it solved the problem, no errors.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out!